# M1 Pro Macbook Pro + Ultrawide locked at 30Hz

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

#### Hardware

- MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021), Apple M1 Pro, running Monterey 12.6
- ASUS MX38V Ultrawide 3840x1600.

#### Expectation

Ultrawide refuses to run at 60Hz, defaulting to 30Hz. In most cases, the option is not available, but see below.

I separately have a 16 intel macbook pro, and this can run the monitor at 60Hz with no issues, see below.

#### Connections

- HDMI, using built in in HDMI port. 30Hz at native resolution, no option for better. Not really surprised by this. I've not tested this with my intel macbook pro.
- 8K@60Hz Stouchi Thunderbolt to Display port. Identical behaviour (30Hz), but with my intel macbook pro this runs at 60Hz fine.
- Supplied USB-C (Thunderbolt?) to USB-C port on the monitor. This supplies power to the laptop, acting as a dock. This runs at 30Hz, but interestingly the option for 75Hz appears. When 75 Hz selected, the monitor immediately loses signal to the laptop, and the laptop periodically stops recognising the monitor as being connected, with about five second intervals of connection/disconnection. This connection type works fine with the intel macbook, supplying power and running at 60Hz.

#### Tried fixes

- In all cases the laptop has been tested with power adaptor connected.
- Both displays are set to Resolution: Default for display. Changing this changes nothing.
- Holding the option key when selecting scaled shows a variety of resolutions, only unusably low resolutions allow for 60Hz.
- Have tried EasyRes, this just provides a slightly more comprehensive user interface to confirm the above.
- Have tried all laptop ports.

Answer (score 1):

I would totally open a support case with Apple. You’ve done an excellent job controlling for every single thing I would do except possibly spend even more on redundant / diverse thunderbolt and [DisplayPort 2.0 cables and adapters](https://vesa.org/press/vesa-publishes-displayport-2-0-video-standard-enabling-support-for-beyond-8k-resolutions-higher-refresh-rates-for-4k-hdr-and-virtual-reality-applications/).

The [Stouchi USB cable is only DP 1.4](https://stouchi.net/de/products/ctdp) and explicitly calls out another ASUS it will not work with:

> Stouchi USB C to DP1.4 adapter supports resolutions 8K (7680x4320) @60Hz, 5K (5120x2880) @ 60Hz, 5120x1440@120Hz,4K(3840x2160) @60Hz/120Hz/144Hz, 2K@120Hz/240Hz. Backwards compatible with DisplayPort 1.3, 1.2 and 1.1.( Note：Not work for Samsung odyssey G7,ASUS VP249QGR, Asus VG249Q)

Unless the display can lock 60 Hz in, you’ll need driver level diagnosis from Apple engineering to confirm you don’t have an easy fix here.

Comment: Thanks, have escalated with Apple. I'll update once I know more in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Apple support suggested that this monitor requires a firmware update to work with M1 chips. I have contacted ASUS, and they are not planning on providing a firmware update for this monitor, so I'm not sure there is a resolution here.

Comment: Ugh - I suppose knowing the issue is better long run, but you may be right on having to settle at half the refresh you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue related to the Macbook hardware which has nothing to do with the firmware of the monitor. As a matter of fact I can use it  with my M1 Mac Mini at 75hz but it's locked at 30hz on my Mac book.

I'm still in the process to understand with Apple why that is the case.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/332596)